How to make clickable link compatible with IDEs and mkdocs?
My docstrings contain links. I want to make these links clickable in IDE, but I want to use the https://github.com/mkdocstrings/python to generate mkdocs api reference.
I want to use this package, because the rest of my documentation is in markdown and thus generated using mkdocs too, and it's easier to tweak it than to merge mkdocs with e.g. sphinx.
I know there are 3 python docstring formats the mkdocs can process: https://mkdocstrings.github.io/griffe/docstrings/
google, numpy and sphinx. I went through the documentation of individual formats:

https://sphinx-rtd-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docstrings.html#the-sphinx-docstring-format
https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html
https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html

but did not find the satisfying answer:
I have tried to put the following links to my docstring:
def foo():
"""

link1
`Example <http://www.example.com>`_
 
link2
`Example <http://www.example.com>`
 
link3
<http://www.example.com>
 
link4
_Example: http://www.example.com
 
link5
_`Example <http://www.example.com>`_
 
link 6
http://www.example.com
 
link7
[example](http://www.example.com)
 
link8
<a href="http://www.example.com">example</a>
"""

which renders the following result in the doc visualization in PyCharm:

then I used
::: my_package_name

for the api reference, and the following mkdocs.yaml is:
plugins:
- search
- mkdocstrings:
    default_handler: python
    handlers:
      python:
        paths: [src]
        options:
          allow_inspection: true
          show_submodules: true

but the rendered html looked like this:

so there is no single format that would be rendered in the same way in both mkdocstring and the native documentation rendering.
Is there any how how to achieve it, or do I need to write my own mkdocs preprocessor?
